# (More) DeclareDesign R Package download problems

Tags: r, installation, declaredesign

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661890/declaredesign-r-package-download-problems) a couple months ago, but the package, website, and code in question have since been updated and the solution I used previously is no longer effective.

The issue is that I am unable to install a particular package in R.

The new code provided for installation of the DeclareDesign package is as follows ([source](https://declaredesign.org)):

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("DeclareDesign/DeclareDesign")
```

I've provided a screenshot of the error that I get when I try to run the above code. It looks to me like the problem is with the included 'estimatr' package, which apparently then causes the entire installation to fail.

How do I get this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeclareDesign is now on CRAN, so you can install via

```
install.packages("DeclareDesign")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your installation failed because devtools is trying to install estimatr from source, but you don't have the appropriate toolchain available to build it.

DeclareDesign now has a drat repository with pre-built binary packages for Mac and Windows, which should obviate the need to install Xcode or Rtools.

```
install.packages("DeclareDesign", repos="http://r.declaredesign.org")
```